# Declaring a static variable in a non-static class in Java

Tags: java, variables, static, variable-declaration

I am new to java. I am currently reading some articles about static variables. When I am trying to implement my learnings, I encountered a problem about static variables. Here is the first code sample.

```
public class Human {
    // in Human.java
    public static int population = 0;
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
         System.out.println(population);
    }
}
```

This code works fine and the outcome is 0.
But for the following code, I wasn't allow to compile it.

```
public class Human {
    // in Human.java
    public class Charlie extends Human {
        public static int number = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
         System.out.println(new Human().new Charlie().number);
    }
}
```

An error occurred: The field number cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression

I am confused with this situation. For the first code sample, my Human class is non-static and I was allowed to declare a static variable inside it. How come I can't do the same for my second code sample.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `public static final int number = 0;` because Java does not let you define non-final static fields inside function-local inner classes. Only top-level classes and static nested classes are allowed to have non-final static fields.

From the [JLS section 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.

Other way to make inner class static and access it

```
public class Human {
    // in Human.java
    public static class Charlie extends Human {
        public static  int number = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
         System.out.println(new Human.Charlie().number);
    }
}
```

Comment: other way would be making the charlie class static. might be worth mentioning

Comment: I see. Are there any reasons for Java to have this restriction? Does this implies that the Java VM treats inner class different from outer class?

Comment: @FunnyFunkyBuggy because Inner class is instance of class. There is no meaning to have static variable in instance itself.